# How to Parse YAML model using IIB?

Tags: parsing, yaml, ibm-integration-bus

I want to create model to parse YAML data in IIB 9. How do I create YAML parser to parse the data?
Since YAML is superset of JSON I cannot use JSON parser right ?
Do I use DFDL parser to create schema then? if so how do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

IIB does not have a YAML parser (domain). I don't recommend using DFDL to parse a data format like YAML. Probably the best option is to use a JavaCompute node to parse the YAML using one of the free class libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is not handle as a Parser.

Your solution is the one I would choose too (BLOB input + Java to convert it), but if you have a YAML input, you probably have to reply with YAML as well, and thus that might be interesting to create a generic flow receive the YAML request, converting it into XML, forwarding it to you application, then receiving an XML and finaly replying with a YAML. This would allow you to do it for other applications without having to care about the YAML anymore.